# How to change color of lines depending on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to make a graph using ggplot about the historic life expectancy of countries only from Europe and the Americas, from a dataframe. My idea was to make the lines from all European countries blue and the Americas red.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(AmericasEuropeData, aes(x = year, y = lifeExp, group = country, color = country)) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = country_colors) +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.text = element_text(size = rel(1.1))) +
  ggtitle("Americas + Europe") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=2020, linetype="dashed") +
  ylab("Life Expectancy") +
  xlab("Year")
```

which displays the following graph:

[image: Combined graph]

I tried changing `color = country` to `color = continent` but it turned all of the lines grey instead of a different color for each continent.
How can I solve this ? I know I am probably messing up something really simple.

Preview of the `AmericasEuropeData` dataframe

[image: dataframe]

Comment: What happens with `group = country, color = continent` when you remove the line `scale_color_manual(values = country_colors) +` ?

Comment: Do a ```dput(AmericasEuropeData)``` and post the result here so I can reproduce your result.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks man I think that made it worked ! I removed ```scale_color_manual(values = country_colors)``` and changed ```color = continent```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked perfectly by changing `color = country` to `color = continent` and removing `scale_color_manual(values = country_colors)` as @AllanCameron said.

This is how it looks now:

[image: final image]